# Note sure why JQuery Draggable not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

Have a group of documents I'd like to make draggable via JQuery, and eventually sortable.
[image]
Those boxs are pure CSS generated and like I said I'd like to keep them the same but draggable. As it is now those notes based off a mongoid db and I can create and destroy successfully using ajax, of course. but I've yet had any luck getting any type of dragging to work. Below is the relevant code.
googling I, atleast hopelly, do not see any issues with code so maybe my jquery is corrupt?
If my code is correct what steps can I take to make sure query-ui is being properly loaded with draggable function...
Thank you for you help
application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

app/views/documents/_document

```
<li>
    <div id=<%= dom_id(document) %> class="document">
    <div class="note">
      <h2><%= document.title %></h2>
      <p></p>
      <%= link_to content_tag(:i, "", class: "icon-trash"), document, method: :delete, remote: true %>
    </div>
  </div>
  </li>
```

app/views/users/index.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
    <div class="notes">
      <ul>
        <%= link_to documents_path, method: :post, remote: true  do %>
        <li>
          <div class="note">
            <h2> </h2>
            <p>create</p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <% end %>
      </li>
      <div id="documents">
        <%= render @documents %>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

/app/assets/javascripts/document.js.coffee

```
JQuery ->
    $( ".note" ).draggable();
```

Comment: Are there any errors in browser console? Because your code looks close to correct (although I would make the li element draggable, and remove the child div and link_to that's incorrectly placed within ul element, to clean things up).

Comment: I am not getting any errors in thin, it is serving the query-ui.js asset, and yes i agree it does need cleaning up

Comment: Found the problem, i had "JQuery ->" not "jQuery ->"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem, i had "JQuery ->" not "jQuery ->" –